# row to create two rows on appbar flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

How to create appbar like the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways (that I know of) to achieve this

**With Appbar**
You can use the `flexibleSpace` property inside of AppBar combining with `SafeArea` to achieve this.

```
AppBar(
  flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
    child: Column(...)
  )
...
)
```

**With Body**
You can use `Stack` and the `Positioned` widget

```
body: Stack(
  child: Positioned(
     top: 0
     child: ...
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, the `AppBar` widget has a parameter called `appBar` which is of type `PreferredSize`. The `PreferredSize` class has two parameters of its own: `child` and `preferredSize`. You can create your own widget and set it as the value for the `appBar` parameter of the `AppBar` widget by using these parameters. You can create something like

```
class CustomAppBar extends PreferredSize {
  const CustomAppBar({
    super.key,
    required super.child,
    required super.preferredSize,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

and assign it to your appBar widget

The final code will look like

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(
        preferredSize: Size(width, height),
        child: const Column(
          children: [
            Row(),
            Column(),
          ],
        ),
      )
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Example'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```